# How to execute a MySQL bulk insert with foreign keys and set to NULL if invalid

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm importing several hundred thousands of rows coming from a service's xml data that has foreign keys pointing from `screenings.venue_id` to the `venues` table.

However I found out that some of their data has missing `venues` so bulk insert fails.

Is there a way to automatically set `screenings.venue_id` to `NULL` if the foreign key fails? I would really like to keep the foreign key for data cohesion and cascade update/delete without using triggers.

So far my best idea is to disable the foreign key checks before insert. This would work for initial import however this means that every time a screening is saved and has an invalid foreign key, it would fail.

Answer (score 2):

For Subsequent inserts I would try this way..

1. Create a separate landing table which is doesn't have FK relation.
2. Create a Before insert Trigger on that landing table which verifies whether the Venue_ID exists on Venue Master table. If it exists then insert will continue if not you can skip the insert or insert those bad rows in another log table for future reference.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's a good idea to separate good vs bad, didn't think about that. Won't the trigger check on every single of these bulk insert be the same as manually checking the validity of the foreign key before the insert though?

Comment: If you use FOR EACH ROW, trigger will check every row that is inserted. It will be similar to checking them manually, except its done by trigger.

It will slow your insert little bit (as it has to cross check another table). Please make sure other table is indexed.